# Datagrid only returning empty rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my C# app. When the application is loaded I see that the datagrid has no rows which is correct as no data has been loaded. The user can then click a button to load some data. This data should be reflected in the datagrid but it is not. All that happens is 12 empty rows are visibile. The 12 empty rows is equal to the number of records I expect to see.

When I step through the code I can see my underlying object (PayOffWin) does contain data in all the fields and 12 items in the list. For some reason this data is not being reflected in my datagrid though and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="dgPayoffWin" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="20"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PayOffWin}"
                        Style="{StaticResource dgBase}"
                        CanUserAddRows="False"
                        CanUserDeleteRows="False"                          
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Range" Binding="{Binding Path=Group}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Frequency" Binding="{Binding Path=WinNum}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Value" Binding="{Binding Path=WinGain}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Code Behind in my view model

```
 List<ResultHolder.PayOffMatrix> _payOffWin;

 public List<ResultHolder.PayOffMatrix> PayOffWin
    {
        get { return _payOffWin; }
        set
        {
            _payOffWin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PayOffWin");
        }
    }


public class PayOffMatrix
        {
            public enumOutCome OutCome;
            public string Group;
            public double LimitUp, LimitDown;
            public double WinNum, WinGain, LossNum, LossGain;
            public double WinProb, WinExpect, LossProb, LossExpect;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just bind to PUBLIC PROPERTIES so just change your fields in PayOffMatrix into public properties

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
List<ResultHolder.PayOffMatrix> PayOffWin;
```

to:

```
ObservableCollection<ResultHolder.PayOffMatrix> PayOffWin;
```

It will work, Lists dont Notify to the view Automaticaly.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro. I take it if implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface this issue should go away as well. My other datagrids are working and the underlying objects implement this interface

Comment: Even if you'll implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, views are updated from the list only in the first loading of the application. Therefore you have always to use the ObservableCollections, to ensure that the Notifications will be done when any update is done.